# UPNP Advertise on Linux and discover on windows?

Tags: c, linux, windows, upnp

**How to public/announce over Linux:**
GSSDP (libgssdp in most linux distros) is a small, reliable and well tested library that handles the announcement and discovery part of UPnP: it's trivial to write a small program that advertizes the device uri with GSSDP (see example https://git.gnome.org/browse/gssdp/tree/tests/test-publish.c).

**How do discover on Linux**:

```
gssdp-discover
```

**Useful Packages:**

```
sudo apt-get install gssdp-tools 
sudo apt-get install gupnp-tools 
sudo apt-get install libgssdp-1.0-dev  // For developing C program
```

**Question:**
How do we discover on Windows what is advertised in test-publish.c (above)  on Linux? Preferred Languages are C++/C and C#. Popular Windows platforms starting from Windows XP needs to be supported.

Once we have this answered we have a compact system to announce on Linux and discover devices both on Windows and Linux.

Comment: You should probably add some details to the windows part of the question. Does the solution need to work in a specific language? Which Windows versions (new ones have a SSDP service implementation that could be useful)?